# Error in Cholesky decomposition when using Bayesian Optimization

Tags: r, machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameters

So, I've been using Bayesian optimization ([rBayesianOptimization](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rBayesianOptimization/index.html)) to tune the hyperparamters of machine learning models based cross-validation performance metrics. Every now and then, I have encountered the following error after a few iterations of Bayesian optimization:

```
Error in chol.default(x = Sig): the leading minor of order XXX is not positive definite.
```

Unfortunately, I can't share my dataset for a reproducible example and the issue occurs somewhat irregularly (I haven't pinpointed what exactly is causing the problem). It appears that, in these cases, there is an issue with the covariance matrix produced my the specified kernel for the Gausian process causing it not to be positive definite.

What's causing this and how can it be dealt with?

Comment: Please post a [mre] (the fact that you are self-answering does not make it optional).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your note. I'd be happy to post my example but, unfortunately, I can't share my dataset. It occurs irregularly for me and I don't have the time right now to go searching for a public dataset where this happens again.  

I know that [others ran into the same issue](https://github.com/yanyachen/rBayesianOptimization/issues/44) with the mentioned packages and wanted to make my solution available.

Answer (score 3):

This error appears to be caused while fitting the [Gaussian process](https://github.com/cran/GPfit/blob/c627d0a2164f9ed6e22b9b5bbed1a68ff4dd501a/R/GP_deviance.R#L164), which underlies Bayesian optimization. The problem is that the covariance matrix produced with the specified kernel is not positive definite. I would be curious to hear in which cases this tends to happen (I've observed this to occur after a set of similar parameters was tested a few times consecutively). I was able to avoid this error by switching from the default kernel (exponential) to matern, which can be done by adding the following argument to the Bayesian optimization call:

```
kernel = list(type = "matern", nu = 5/2)
```